# how to write this in a for loop in R?

Tags: for-loop

I have wrote this

```
pp1<-table(sip$newSS4_1 [sip$newSS4_1==1], sip$HS1C1 [sip$newSS4_1==1])
pp1=round(prop.table(pp1,1), digits=3)
pp1
```

i have 30 variables to do. for example:

```
pp2<-table(sip$newSS4_2 [sip$newSS4_2==1], sip$HS1C1 [sip$newSS4_2==1])
pp2=round(prop.table(pp2,1), digits=3)
pp2
```

and `pp3`...`pp30` so on. I have`newSS4_1`...`newSS4_30`in dataframe already.

How to write this in a loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Show some of your data to make it reproducible

Comment: This is a basic programming question and has nothing to do with any particular language.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just a very beginner and trying to do data cleaning. Sorry for the dumb question if it bothered you.@CarlWitthoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are making things hard for yourself.

1. Instead of creating 30 variables with different names, why not use a single list?
2. Instead of using column names, why not use column numbers?

`pp <- list()
    colnums <- grep(names(sip), "newSS4_") # assuming they are in order
    for (i in 1:30) {
        cn <- colnums[i]
        pp[[i]] <- table(sip[,cn ] [sip[,cn]==i], sip$HS1C1 [ sip[,cn]==i ])
    }`

If you really want to have different variables, you can use

```
assign(paste0("pp", i), value)
```

to assign to e.g. pp1, pp2, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because I am a beginner. I dont understand what do you mean by "use a single list"? and I am not using row names. I'm using column names and yes I can use column numbers. It's just I don't know how to do that...  @dash2

Comment: I mean that you should not create 30 variables called `pp1`, `pp2` etc. Instead, create a single variable called `pp`, which is a list with 30 elements, `pp[[1]]`, `pp[[2]]` et cetera.